# GitLab CI build fails with git is not recognized

Tags: git, command-line, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have set up a GitLab pipeline, and configured a runner. The build starts when I make a commit, but fails almost immediately with the following message:

```
C:\GitLabRunner\builds\xxxxxxxx\0\cmac\portal>"git" "checkout" "-f" "-q" 
   "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" 

 '"git"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
   operable program or batch file.

C:\GitLabRunner>IF 9009 NEQ 0 exit /b 9009 
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 9009
```

This is my .gitlab-ci.yml, which I have stripped right back to try and isolate the issue:

```
stages:
 - build
variables:
  CI_DEBUG_TRACE: "true"
Build:
  stage: build
  script:
     - Echo OK
```

The only similar issues I could find are [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/issues/193) and [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/issues/1799)

I thought I had fixed the issue when I was getting the same message in a when trying to use git in a standard command prompt as my PATH wasn't set correctly in Environment variables.

However I have now fixed this and I am getting expected responses back from git through the command prompt, however I still get the issue when gitlab kicks off the build.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just remove the double quotes and it should be fine

Comment: Do you mean the quotes around this: "git" "checkout" "-f" "-q" ? That is auto generated by the gitlab build which I don't have any control over

Comment: Yes, remove them all

Comment: What I'm saying is I can't remove the quotes because the gitlab build generates the script and runs it, it isn't possible to remove them

Comment: Ok, just one more check.... can you open a command line and `cd` to this folder `C:\GitLabRunner\builds\xxxxxxxx\0\cmac\portal`, then run the following command in the cmd `git status`....

Comment: Yes I've already done that and it recognises git both through bash and cmd

Comment: @DeclanMcNulty I am dealing with simillar problem, error message is for maven that is recognized in bash (mvn) as it is git in your case.

Comment: I have the same problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49155380/git-is-not-recognized-in-windows-gitlab-ci

Comment: One reason for "is not recognized as an internal or external command" can be that the gitlab-runner service runs as SYSTEM and the program you are trying to execute within the pipeline runs as your Windows user. I actually had this one time with `cargo`, because Rust is installed per user.

Answer (score 1):

After you install new applications on your buildmachine restart gitlab runner to pick up path.

Comment: More generally, when you modify the environment variables you have to restart the gitlab runner to update its environment.

Answer (score 1):

I use `gitlab-ci` with powershell as executor.
Add the git path `C:\Program Files\Git\bin` to `$PATH` fixed this problem

Comment: In my case "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd" was already added when i installed GIT but after adding the path "C:\Program Files\Git\bin" to the PATH environment variable the issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Installing Git to `c:\Git` instead of `c:\Program Files...` fixed this problem for me

Answer (score 0):

Did you install git on the CI? In my `.gitlab-ci.yml` solved this by adding `apk update && apk add git` to the `before_script`, like so:

```
# Make sure to install all packages before running anything.
before_script:
  - apk update && apk add git
  - npm ci # For CI it's better to have this instead of npm install.
```