# GitLab pipeline fails frequently even after trying in many ways

Tags: angular, git, gitlab

I was just trying to work with GitLab CI/CD. I created a test angular project which had only one component, and worked fine. Then I started the GitLab Runner in that project. Added a .yml file to run the project. But the pipeline failed all the time. Then for testing purpose, I removed all the scripts for running the project, and just added some echo statements. Even then my pipeline failed.
It is showing that

> & : The term 'git' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
>   spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Screenshot of yml script

[image]

Error message showed in GitLab

[image]

Comment: This means that the "git" command cannot be found. Is Git installed on your build runner host and available in PATH?

Comment: I have added the PATH. And Git is installed globally.

Comment: Show the contents of your gitlab runner toml configuration file, I don't where is the path on Windows machine, But it should be something like `config.toml` in "C:\GitLab-Runner\".

Answer (score 0):

This is because git is not available in your runner path.

1. Make sure Git is installed in your runner

```
before_script:
  - apt-get install git-core
```

2. If installed try restarting the runner instance

Issue Links-

1. https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/2743
2. [Git is not recognized in Windows gitlab ci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49155380/git-is-not-recognized-in-windows-gitlab-ci)

Comment: Please could you tell me how do I install Git in my runner? I have tried many ways, so I think I might have done it. But I am not sure about which step are you refering to.

Comment: `apt-get` will not work in a powershell script/runner.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled my git and reinstalled it. The location I provided for environment path was different, than the one in which the git was actually installed at. Hence, when I reinstalled it, it got automatically installed into my C drive(this was the environment path I had set, I got this path while I was searching for solutions in net).
I had not cross checked, whether actually my git location was C or not. I thought it might have been saved in C itself, but it was actually saved in some other location.

Answer (score 0):

After installing the `git` from [git-scm.com](https://git-scm.com/downloads) you must restart the `gitlab-runner` service.

I had problem in windows server and eventually become fixed :)

```
# gitlab-runner stop
# gitlab-runner start
```